# Azure Blob Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am accessing a website that allows me to download CSV file. I would like to store the CSV file directly to the blob container. I know that one way is to download the file locally and then upload the file, but I would like to skip the step of downloading the file locally. Is there a way in which I could achieve this.

i tried the following:

```
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path('containername','blobname','https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/containername/FlightStats',content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='application/CSV'))
```

but I keep getting errors stating path is not found.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The file_path in `create_blob_from_path` is the path of your local file, looks like "C:\xxx\xxx". This path(*'https://*****.blob.core.windows.net/containername/FlightStats'*) is Blob URL.

You could download your file to byte array or stream, then use [`create_blob_from_bytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#create-blob-from-bytes-container-name--blob-name--blob--index-0--count-none--content-settings-none--metadata-none--validate-content-false--progress-callback-none--max-connections-2--lease-id-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--timeout-none-) or [`create_blob_from_stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#create-blob-from-stream-container-name--blob-name--stream--count-none--content-settings-none--metadata-none--validate-content-false--progress-callback-none--max-connections-2--lease-id-none--if-modified-since-none--if-unmodified-since-none--if-match-none--if-none-match-none--timeout-none--use-byte-buffer-false-) method.

Answer (score 0):

Other answer uses the so called "Azure SDK for Python ***legacy***".

---

I recommend that if it's fresh implementation then use Gen2 Storage Account (instead of Gen1 or Blob storage).

For Gen2 storage account, see [example here](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.0.0b7/index.html#id3):

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

data = b"abc"
file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string("my_connection_string",
                                                 file_system_name="myfilesystem", file_path="myfile")

file.append_data(data, offset=0, length=len(data))
file.flush_data(len(data))
```

It's painful, if you're appending multiple times then you'll have to keep track of `offset` on client side.